# Show that $ab=ba^k$, if any subgroup of a group is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

"Let $G$ be a group and suppose that all subgroups of $G$ are normal subgroups. Show that, for all $a,b\in G$, there exists $k\in Z$ such that $ab=ba^k$"

I tried to write $ab=b(b^{-1}ab)$ but I can't conclude anything. I'm stuck in here... Is there any need of separating the problem in cases?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The subgroup $H = \langle a \rangle$ generated by $a$ is normal. This means that $bH = Hb$ for any $b \in G$. In particular, $ab \in bH$...